# How to access exoplayer instance from MediaBrowserServiceCompat in activity?

Tags: android, exoplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowserservice

I have used exoplayer for playing audio from local files in a `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`. I read about exoplayer ui and want to use that in my activity. How do I get instance of exoplayer in my activity so that I can call the method `playbackcontrolview.setplayer(exoplayer)` to bind it with exoplayer ui?

I have already tried using `IBinder` like normal service but it throws error.

I want to bind my exoplayer ui in activity to the exoplayer instance in `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

Comment: what error it is giving and attach your code.

Comment: Can you post some code how you do this?